# Laravel - Class 'JeroenDesloovere\VCard\VCard' not found

Tags: laravel, vcf-vcard

I'm using Laravel 9, and when I click the button, I want it to save the values on the phone. I'm using '[jeroendesloovere/vcard](https://github.com/jeroendesloovere/vcard)' for this but when i call my function i get such error:

**Class 'JeroenDesloovere\VCard\VCard' not found**

Where am I missing? Where is my fault?

**Controller:**

```
use JeroenDesloovere\VCard\VCard;


public function vcards($name,$phone){
        $vcard = new VCard();
        // define variables
        $lastname = 'Desloovere';
        $firstname = 'Jeroen';
        $additional = '';
        $prefix = '';
        $suffix = '';
        // add personal data
        $vcard->addName($lastname, $firstname, $additional, $prefix, $suffix);
    }
```

**Blade.php**

```
<a href="#" onclick="{{HomeController::vcards($userData->full_name,$userData->masked_phone_number)}}" class="btn btn-info">add</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

The package is not installed
You can install it using

```
composer require jeroendesloovere/vcard
```

Comment: i already install